# How to convert object which is like to json object to c#?

Tags: c#

I have an object returned from API. It is very like to json but it is not. I printed it in visual studio immediate window. Something like.

```
[0]: {{
   "projectId": 111,
   "userId": 11,
   "name": "Bill, Gates",
   "value": "11"
 }}
[1]: {{
   "projectId": 222,
   "userId": 22,
   "name": "Cill, Gates",
   "value": "22"
 }}
  // .....many
```

It is not json type. So I use cast

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> list = obj.Cast<object>();
 public class MyClass
  {
     public int projectId {get; set;}
     public int userId {get; set;}
     public string name {get; set;}
     public string value {get; set;}
  }
```

However when I loop through the list

```
  foreach(var item in list)
  {
      var temp = item.value;
  }
```

I can't get item or temp. Hover it or print it in the immediate window; it shows

> NullReferenceException

I assume that I have to convert the object to real json type rather then using `cast<object>`.
So what is the best way?

Comment: It is not globally json standard format, prefer to create correctly json from API

Comment: you have two options: 1 create your own parser ( deserializer ) that interprets the format you are showing..... 2 change the string to valid json then deserialize it to a c # object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
json = Regex.Replace(json, @"\[[0-9]+\]:", ""); // remove [0]:
json = json.Replace("{{", "{"); 
json = json.Replace("}}", "},");
json = $"[{json}]";

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

might need more work if you have more nested objects

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I was experimenting with your string and trying to use `Regular Expressions` and I have found a way to parse your string into your corresponding `MyClass` structure. I hope this helps you out:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string str = @"[0]: {{
                               'projectId': 111,
                               'userId': 11,
                               'name': 'Bill, Gates',
                               'value': '11'
                             }}
                            [1]: {{
                               'projectId': 222,
                               'userId': 22,
                               'name': 'Cill, Gates',
                               'value': '22'
                             }}";

        try
        {
         showMatch(str, @"('(.*)':(.*)[',])");      
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
         Console.WriteLine("Exception occured: "+ex.Message);
        }
    }

    static private void showMatch(string text, string expr)
    {
        //Declare what is required! Phew
        List<MyClass> output = new List<MyClass>();
        int projectId=0;
        int userId=0;
        string name=string.Empty;
        string value=string.Empty;

        var regEx = new Regex(@"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+");

        //Start the matching process
        MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(text, expr);
        bool check;
        foreach (Match m in mc)
        {
            check = false;
            string[] parsed = m.ToString().Split(':');
            var stripped = regEx.Replace(parsed[1], "");
            if (parsed[0] == "'projectId'")
            {
                projectId = Convert.ToInt32(stripped);
            }
            if (parsed[0] == "'userId'")
            {
                userId = Convert.ToInt32(stripped);
            }
            if (parsed[0] == "'name'")
            {
                name = stripped;
            }
            if (parsed[0] == "'value'")
            {
                value = stripped;
                check = true;
            }

            //Add to list
            if(check==true)
            {
                output.Add(new MyClass { projectId = projectId, userId = userId, name = name, value = value });
            }
        }

        output.Dump();
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int projectId { get; set; }
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
[
   {
   name       : BillGates
   projectId  : 111
   userId     : 11
   value      : 11
   },
   {
   name       : CillGates
   projectId  : 222
   userId     : 22
   value      : 22
   }
]
```

Working DEMO: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TCXVde